# Show that the polynomial $p$ that is defined as a determinant is linear in $x$

Tags: linear-algebra, algebra-precalculus

We have a matrix:

[image]

We have a polynomial defined as:

[image]

We need to show that this polynomial is linear in $x$:

What I tried:
1.) $(p+q)(x) = p(x)+q(x)$ .... here I do not know  how to separate the sum of the determinant, I refreshed my memory of properties of the determinants, and there is no property, where I could just split $x$ and $a_{ij}$.

2.) $(\alpha p)(x) = \alpha p(x)$ ... I think we also need to show this as the second property of linearity.

Comment: Hint: Subtract the first row from the other rows. And then the first column from the other columns.

Comment: I think what you're asked to do is show that it is a linear polynomial in $x$. You are trying to show that something is linear in $p$ (and as we don't know the definition of $q(x)$ and so on it doesn't make sense, does it?

Comment: @ancientmathematician I see... how would I show that it is linear at $x$, looks like I havent done any similar problems...

Comment: It is not linear in $x$ it is a linear polynomial (there's a constant term $\det A$). The answer by @WhatsUp tells you what to do.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Simply subtract the first row from every other row. This operation doesn't change the determinant.

After that, there is only $x$ in the first row. You then expand the determinant with respect to the first row.